# Android How to Add add an seekbar on notification Panel

Tags: android, notifications, slider

I want to add a slider to a notification,I use seekbar, but I'm wrong.
I want to use this slider to control the volume，help me.

Comment: That there is no way to achieve such a slider in the notification bar？

Comment: OK, can you teach me how to do it，Or, what are the examples，please！